# Cannot update identity column "PartyID"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-3.1

I upgraded project .net core sdk 2.2 to .net core sdk 3.1. My project is working well with .net core sdk 2.2. Party class exist in my project, I get that "Cannot update identity column "PartyID"" when I try to update party name. PartyID is primary key and increment by one by in sql table. Have you any idea?

```
public class Parties
{

    public Parties()
    {
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PartyID { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I researched this error on web and I added below code.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var partiesBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Parties>();
        partiesBuilder.Property(p => p.PartyID).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
        partiesBuilder.Property(p => p.PartyID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
        partiesBuilder.Property(p => p.PartyID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
```

However I get this error :
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'PartyID' on entity type 'Parties' must be marked as read-only after it has been saved because it is part of a key. Key properties are always read-only once an entity has been saved for the first time.'".

Also I used this package:
EntityFramework version 6.4.4, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 3.1.6

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3239),and try to set `IsModified` or `IsReadonly `.

Comment: why are you using 6.4.4 with EF Core installed?

Comment: Actually, I used hierarchyId sql type in another entity class. I know that EF Core 6.4.4 is suitable to hierarchyId and .net core sdk 3.1.  Do you think the problem is caused by this version?